# Want to Make Devices(Connected) Whitelisted for my Hotspot in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager, hot-spot

I have made my Ubuntu machine as **Hotspot** point.Now I want to make some devices **whitelisted** so that other people will not be abe to use my wifi. I have googled some stuffs but nothing was that much helpfull.

How can i do this in my ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: There is no way to "keep wifi open" and prevent other users from using it. It is not related to Ubuntu at all. You can have mac filtering, but it is quite easy to override.

Comment: ok. Then can i make devices whitelisted ?

Comment: You can, but it wont help much.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: It is useless and I never tried it with an Ubuntu hotspot.

Comment: Btw my question wasnt about "how secure it will be" .. but "how can i make whiltelist" !